# Adding strings together to get img path based on attribute in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to display an image using a string built from several values? Ie. I want to show an image whose path contains an attribute value. Example of my code (which doesn't work):

```
<img src="{'subdirectory/' + @title + '150p.png'}" />
```

This tries, and fails, to display an image with the path "subdirectory/main150p.png" if the current node's "title" attribute = "main".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be thinking in Javascript instead of in XPath.  Try `<img src="{concat('subdirectory/', @title, '150p.png')}" />`